# Intrinsic parameters OpenCV explanation

Tags: opencv

I measured intrinsic camera parameters with the OpenCv algorithm. The imager has an resolution of (752,480)

The values are :

Focal Length X  1021.477666;

Focal Length Y  1021.146888

Principal Point X 376.2966754
Principal Point Y 253.7513058

K1 -0.263658008

K2 -0.206264024

P1 -0.001102641

P2 -0.000980475

Error 0.122991565

Now I want to calculate the distorsion of one pixel.
The coordinates of the "old" pixel are

(x = 680,y = 390).

I´m using the following formula to calculate the coordinates of the corrected pixel

x_{corrected} = x( 1 + k_1 r^2 + k_2 r^4)
y_{corrected} = y( 1 + k_1 r^2 + k_2 r^4)

For **r** I´m using the distance

r = sqrt((x_shifted^2 - x_principalPoint^2)+(y_shifted^2 - y_principalPoint^2))

The calculation I did :

x_corrected = 680 * ( 1 + (-0.26365 * 333^2) + (-0.2062 + 333^2 ) )

= 55524658.09

This value is incorrect I think.

Does anyone have an idea what I´m doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to express your undistorted points in normalised coordinates. So you need to convert it first:

```
x_norm = (x-px)/px = 0.8071
```

and

```
y_norm = (y-py)/py = 0.5369
```

Then calculate the radius:

```
r = sqrt(x_norm^2+y_norm^2)
```

With these values you get your corrrected normalizes coordinates :

```
x_corr_norm =  x_norm*(1+k1*r^2+k2*r^4) = 0.4601
y_corr_norm = y_norm*(1+k1*r^2+k2*r^4) = 0.3061
```

and you have to convert them back again:

```
x_corr = (x_corr_norm+1)*px = 549.4409
y_corr = (y_corr_norm+1)*py = 331.4280
```

For a more accurate result, you should consider the non-radial distortion too:
[image]